# What is Abstract and Composite Types and how can I use them efficiently? (Julia Language)

Tags: julia

Julia programming language has a very strong structure and usage for datatypes. I have read the original documentation of Julia but I didn't understand the 'defining a datatype' part. How can I use the datatype which is defined by me? For example

```
abstract type newType
end

datatype(a::newType) = return a

datatype(12)
```

results in

````
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching datatype(::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  datatype(::newType) at REPL[5]:1```
````

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Instead post the code as text in a code block. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This question does not follow SO rules. Perhaps you should start with reading https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/ and than try to write your own example and if it does not work make a question here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basic problem is that you can not instantiate an abstract type in Julia, only a concrete subtype. For example, you can not make a `Number`, but instead can make an `Int` or a `Float` (which are types of `Number`s).